# Time period of a mathematical pendulum

Tags: dynamical-systems

Consider the mathematical pendulum

$$\dot{\theta}=\omega$$
$$\dot{\omega}=-\frac{g}{L}sin\left(\theta\right)$$

How can one prove that it is impossible that the time period $T$ depends only on the length $L$, and the mass $m$, i.e, that there is no such function as $f(T,L,m)=0$.

Comment: Obviously, there is no $m$ in the equation, and the dynamic or time scale depends only on the fraction $\frac{g}{L}$. One could then in the next stage find that the period also depends on the level of the energy function.

Comment: Intuitively, if you make the initial value of $\omega$ large enough, the pendulum reaches the angle $\theta = \pi$ with only a small percentage reduction to $\omega$ and it continues in the same direction indefinitely. Consider what happens if you increase the initial $\omega.$ On the other hand, there's some initial $\omega$ such that $\omega$ goes to zero as $\theta$ approaches $\pi.$

Comment: There is [a nice 3Blue1Brown tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_di4Zn4wz4) starting at 5:55.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly compute the period given the largest angle $θ_\max$ as
$$
T=4\int_0^{θ_\max}\frac{dθ}{\sqrt{2\frac{g}L(\cosθ-\cosθ_\max)}}
=2\sqrt{\frac{L}g}\int_0^{θ_\max}\frac{dθ}{\sqrt{\sin^2(θ_\max/2)-\sin^2(θ/2)}}
$$
So you get a dependence on $\frac{L}{g}$ and $θ_\max$, but not on $m$ and $L$ alone.